# How to send mail with nodemailer (node.js) by direct method?

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I try to write simple mailer just to send some text (for testing purposes) with nodemailer. If I understood well it may sent a mail by smtp or direct. At first I want to sent with DIRECT method.

The next code very simple:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({direct:true,
    host: 'smtp.yandex.ru',
    port: 465,
    auth: { 
        user: 'login@yandex.ru', 
        pass: 'password' },
    secure: true
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'nworksheet@gmail.com',
    to: 'sky-bell@mail.ru',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'This is auto mail sending'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if(error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("Message sent "+info.response)
});
```

But I have the next error:

```
{ Error: Sending failed
at QueryReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:65:16)
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:216:10)
  errors: 
   [ { Error: queryMx ENOTFOUND mail.ru
     at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
     at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:216:19)
   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
   syscall: 'queryMx',
   hostname: 'mail.ru' } ] }
```

What does it mean? How to fix it? Node not see 'mail.ru'? Why?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Yandex',
    auth: { 
        user: 'your_yandex_email', 
        pass: 'your_password_for_email' },
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'your_yandex_email',
    to: 'sky-bell@mail.ru',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'This is auto mail sending'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if(error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("Message sent "+info.response)
});
```

Whenever you specify the **service** command, it automatically sets the port and secures the email.
Also remember to put and fetch the credentials from a config file.

Comment: Bro, I tried it but it said `connect ECONNREFUSED 77.88.21.158:465`, 
What it means?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can't find an MX record for mail.ru. It seems to exist however. https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#MX/mail.ru

Does this machine have DNS set up properly? Can you dig it from that machine?

Comment: Probably, some trouble with MX for mail.ru, i think so. But I changed code into "to: 'sky-bell@mail.ru'," with my google mail:

        to: 'nworksheet@gmail.com',

I checked MX with nslookup:

C:\Users\Alex>nslookup -type=mx gmail.com
╤хЁтхЁ:  srv-s10-dc1.billing.ru
Address:  172.30.0.14

gmail.com.net.billing.ru        MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = smtp.net.bi
lling.ru
It seems all right with this? But when I start my program - received the same error:
.......
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'queryMx',
hostname: 'gmail.com' } ] }

Comment: How can one specify to use the domain in the e-mail and ignore MX lookup failures?  This is for the case of an internal server that can't have any MX records, but accepts mail.